# Prove $\frac{\gamma}{4}+\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{4} \right]=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\zeta(n)}{2^{2n}n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The originate idea of this formula is from [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/sums/zeta.pdf)

(1)

$$\frac{\gamma}{4}+\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4} \right]=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\zeta(n)}{2^{2n}n}$$

We arrived at (1) through many substitution of other results and verifying through the sum calculator. Quite long ago, so I don't know what results I used to get to (1).

Can anyone prove formula (1)?

Comment: Do the square brackets around the argument to the logarithm mean anything (round to nearest? floor?), or are they just for grouping?

Comment: Have you, by any chance, tried to reprove your own result? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: we don't care of a link. write how you get to this formula..

Comment: @user1952009 ?! That's what the question is asking. "They got that a while ago, don't know how to reprove it, ask for help."

Comment: @ClementC. :  I want him to write what he obtains when inverting $\sum$ and $\sum$, because I don't want to do it myself and check 5 times if I didn't do any mistake (and it is obvious that he knows how to do it)

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is just a bracket for grouping

Comment: This result I got 10 years ago, sorry I can't remember. I just need confirmation of its correctness that all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Taylor Series for the [Polygamma Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Taylor_series):
$$
\psi^{(0)}(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\zeta(k+1)z^k
\\=-\gamma+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{n}\zeta(n)z^{n-1}
$$
Integrating both sides between 0 and 1/4 and using the fact that $\psi^{(0)}(z+1)=\frac{d}{dz}(\ln(\Gamma(z+1)))$, you get:
$$
\ln(\Gamma(\frac{5}{4}))-\ln(\Gamma(1))=-\gamma(\frac{1}{4})+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}\zeta(n)}{4^{n}n}
\\\frac{\gamma}{4}+\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{4}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}\zeta(n)}{2^{2n}n}
$$